# Join Tables Conditionally Without a Subquery?

Tags: sql, oracle

In a simplified form, we have two tables - transactional table TR and lookup table ITEM:

Table ITEM:

```
+---------+-----------+
| ITEM_ID | ITEM_DESC |
+---------+-----------+
| AAA     | parent    |
| AAA111  | child abc |
| AAA222  | child xyz |
+---------+-----------+
```

Table TR:

```
+-------+------------+
| TR_ID | TR_ITEM_ID |
+-------+------------+
| 1     | AAA        |
| 2     | AAA111     |
| 3     | AAA222     |
| 4     | AAA333     |
| 5     | AAA444     |
+-------+------------+
```

When we join these two tables, if `TR_ITEM_ID` doesn't exist in the lookup table (e.g. for `AAA333` or `AAA444`) such row must be joined on the "parent" item (i.e. `AAA`). Parent can simply be deduced from the first three letters of the ID. So the desired outcome should be this:

```
+-------+------------+---------+-----------+
| TR_ID | TR_ITEM_ID | ITEM_ID | ITEM_DESC |
+-------+------------+---------+-----------+
| 1     | AAA        | AAA     | parent    |
| 2     | AAA111     | AAA111  | child abc |
| 3     | AAA222     | AAA222  | child xyz |
| 4     | AAA333     | AAA     | parent    |
| 5     | AAA444     | AAA     | parent    |
+-------+------------+---------+-----------+
```

Currently we have a view that does that, but it's using subqueries. e.g.:

```
select * from (
  select TR.*,
    (select ITEM.ITEM_ID from ITEM where TR.TR_ITEM_ID = ITEM.ITEM_ID) CHILD_LOOKUP_TYPE,
    (select ITEM.ITEM_ID from ITEM where substr(TR.TR_ITEM_ID,1,3) = ITEM.ITEM_ID) PARENT_LOOKUP_TYPE
  from TR
) f left outer join ITEM on ITEM.ITEM_ID =
   case
     when f.CHILD_LOOKUP_TYPE is not null then f.CHILD_LOOKUP_TYPE
     when f.PARENT_LOOKUP_TYPE is not null then f.PARENT_LOOKUP_TYPE
   end
order by TR_ITEM_ID;
```

The issue is that if we didn't have subqueries, the view would perform a magnitude faster (there are other joins in the real view, but altogether our estimate is that it'll run close to 10x faster). So the question is, is there a way to rewrite the above view without the subqueries? Or any other suggestion to make the join more efficient?

Here are some restrictions that we have, in case these would make good suggestions:

1. We cannot store "resolved" `ITEM_ID` in the transactional table because we cannot modify the historical data in the customer DB.
2. Even if we could, lookup table will change from time to time (e.g. they may add item `AAA333`), so the "resolved" values would become invalid.
3. We cannot create a materialized view.

Here's some quick SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE ITEM (
  ITEM_ID VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
  ITEM_DESC VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
);
Insert into ITEM (ITEM_ID,ITEM_DESC) values ('AAA','parent');
Insert into ITEM (ITEM_ID,ITEM_DESC) values ('AAA111','child abc');
Insert into ITEM (ITEM_ID,ITEM_DESC) values ('AAA222','child xyz');

CREATE TABLE TR (
  TR_ID NUMBER,
  TR_ITEM_ID VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
);
Insert into TR (TR_ID,TR_ITEM_ID) values (1,'AAA');
Insert into TR (TR_ID,TR_ITEM_ID) values (2,'AAA111');
Insert into TR (TR_ID,TR_ITEM_ID) values (3,'AAA222');
Insert into TR (TR_ID,TR_ITEM_ID) values (4,'AAA333');
Insert into TR (TR_ID,TR_ITEM_ID) values (5,'AAA444');
```

Comment: if item_desc is missing, is it safe to assume it should always be a parent?

Comment: @vkp item_desc is part of the lookup table, those are always present. tr_item_id from the transactional table could be missing, though, in which case we fill desc with "Unknown". but such cases can be resolved with nlv function.

Answer (score 0):

If it can be assumed that the missing item_id's item_desc should always be `parent`, this would be a simple query with a `left join`.

```
select 
 tr.tr_id
,tr.tr_item_id
,coalesce(i.item_id,substr(tr.tr_item_id,1,3)) as item_id
,coalesce(i.item_desc,(select item_desc from item where substring(tr.tr_item_id,1,3)=item_id)) as item_desc
from tr
left join item i on tr.tr_item_id=i.item_id
```

Comment: ok, i understand your question better now :) so, if an item is not in the lookup table, it should be mapped to its parent, so the descriptions for that item should come from the lookup table. so "parent" wording was just an example, it should take whatever is in the lookup table. hopefully i didn't make it more confusing...

Comment: yeah, this works... but it still has a subquery, albeit one less that the original view. i'll try to test this against a larger dataset (million+ rows) to see what the improvement is.

Comment: so on a large dataset this resulted in an improvement of about 22%.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to consider. On the small sample you provided, the optimizer cost is 7, vs. 13 for the original query. Try it on your large dataset though.

Depending on your Oracle version (which you should always include with your questions), column aliases in the factored subquery declaration (`with` clause) may or may not work; if you are on 11.1 or before, they may need to be moved within the factored subquery.

The idea is to do a left join first, and "save" it (which is what a factored subquery does). Then select all the rows where the `item_desc` is not `null`; and do a further join just for the rows that have `null` for `item_desc`.

By the way, can `item_desc` be `null` in the lookup table? I assumed not (it would be unusual in a lookup table); if it **can** be `null`, this can be adapted easily (add `i.item_id` to the `with` clause, and use that to determine which row from `j` goes to which branch of the `union all`).

```
with j ( tr_id, tr_item_id, parent_lookup_type, item_desc ) as (
         select t.tr_id, t.tr_item_id, substr(t.tr_item_id, 1, 3), i.item_desc
         from   tr t left outer join item i on t.tr_item_id = i.item_id
       )
select  tr_id, tr_item_id, tr_item_id as child_lookup_type, parent_lookup_type,
        tr_item_id as item_id, item_desc
  from  j
  where j.item_desc is not null
union all
select  j.tr_id, j.tr_item_id, null, j.parent_lookup_type, j.parent_lookup_type,
        i.item_desc
  from  j left outer join item i on j.parent_lookup_type = i.item_id
  where j.item_desc is null
;
```

Comment: let me take some time to digest this :) but i ran this and the sql that i posted in the question on the same dataset and this runs about 5x faster!

Comment: oh, and yes, as expected item_desc cannot be null

Comment: i spoke too soon... with the order by clause it actually runs about 2x faster. still, a good improvement.

Comment: Oh! I missed the order by completely!